# How to Hide Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to Hide Button Untill I select one of the item from the list if I Selected the Item My Button Should be Visible

like

```
bool visible = false

if(itemSelected is Selected) {
visible = true;
} else {
visible = false;
};
```

Like This ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) class like this:

```
Visibility(
  visible: _isVisible, // bool
  child: myWidgetHere, // widget to show/hide
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example:

```
 bool _canShowButton = true;

  void hideWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _canShowButton = !_canShowButton;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test Screen'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  //color: Colors.white,
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: 400.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ///if the show button is false
              !_canShowButton
                  ? const SizedBox.shrink()
                  : RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Login'),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 7.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () {
                        hideWidget();
                        //_number();
                      },
                    ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Button How Can you Relate to ListView Selected Item ? how the canShowButton Know Were i Selected Items in List or Not ?

Comment: on click on list item make _canShowButton = true. that's it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use `Visibility` Widget .Instead dummy `container` or `sizedbox`.that widget have there own features or properties.

Here we create simple `List<object>` outside the stateful class or you can use `widget.listobject`(**when inside the variable :**so rebuilding the app whenever click on the listview reset the isshow propery so we cant manage the show and hide).

whenever we tap on the listview item the `element.isshow` set to true or false inside `setstate`

```
var getdata = Diohelper.getdata();

class _staState extends State<sta> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List mwidge = [];
    int index = 0;
    getdata.forEach((element) {
      mwidge.add(ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            element.isShow = element.isShow ? false : true;
          });
        },
        hoverColor: Colors.amber,
        title: Text(element.name.toString()),
        trailing: element.isShow
            ? SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          child: OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text(element.name.toString())));
          }, child: Text("Show")),
        )
            : Container(
          width: 100,
        ),
      ));
      index++;
    });
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [...mwidge],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**FullCode:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: sta())));

class sta extends StatefulWidget {
  const sta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<sta> createState() => _staState();
}

var isShow = false;
var getdata = Diohelper.getdata();

class _staState extends State<sta> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List mwidge = [];
    int index = 0;
    getdata.forEach((element) {
      mwidge.add(ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            element.isShow = element.isShow ? false : true;
          });
        },
        hoverColor: Colors.amber,
        title: Text(element.name.toString()),
        trailing: element.isShow
            ? SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                child: MaterialButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Show")),
              )
            : Container(
                width: 100,
              ),
      ));
      index++;
    });
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [...mwidge],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class productModel {
  String? name;
  String? price;
  String? category;
  bool isShow = false;

  productModel({this.name, this.price, this.category, this.isShow = false});

  productModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
    category = json['category'];
    isShow = json['isShow'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['isShow'] = this.isShow;
    return data;
  }
}

class Diohelper {
  static List<productModel> getdata() {
    List<productModel> list = [];
    list.add(productModel(name: "broast", price: "100", category: "chicken"));
    list.add(productModel(name: "mandi", price: "100", category: "chicken"));
    list.add(productModel(name: "mandi", price: "100", category: "veg"));

    return list;
  }
}
```